# Add shipping method by shipping zone in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I want to add a particular shipping method when customer address is within particular shipping zone. While searching through Stackoverflow I found a lot of snippets removing shipping methods based on some criteria but I found none adding shipping methods.
Desired shipping method exists in options, it is disabled by default, it's a flatrate with ID 7.
Here's what I tried:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'add_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_zone', 10, 2 );
function add_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_zone( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    $shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( $package );
    $zone_id   = $shipping_zone->get_id();

    if ( $zone_id == 3) {
        // some magic here to add an existing shipping method which was disabled in shipping options
        $rates[] = 'flat_rate:7'; // this does not work, looks like I have to insert all shipping method properties as well
    }
    
    return $rates;

}
```

Zone matching logics are working as expected but I was not able to figure out how I can add an existing shipping method to $rates object.
Also I was not able to print $rates and $package contents through 'woocommerce_package_rates' filter although it seemed to work some time ago. So any suggestion how I can print these objects on cart page is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

When a shipping method is disabled it is not present in `$rates`, so an option is to **enable** it and using some reverse logic

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Shipping zone
    $shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( $package );
    
    // Get zone ID
    $zone_id = $shipping_zone->get_id();

    // NOT equal
    if ( $zone_id != 3 ) {
        // Unset a single rate/method
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:7'] );
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand how to make it work this way, I was interested how to achieve the result the opposite way - via adding shipping method instead of removing it. I suppose I should get desired shipping method instance and append it to $rates object or some other hook should be used...